# Syntax of built in methods in Python

Tags: python, syntax

so there is a string, lets say a='abc' and two built in string methods for that string object (and string class in general):

```
len(a)
a.capitalize()
```

So when is first syntax, `method(object)`, used over the second, `object.method()`  ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: `len` is not a string method. It is a built-in **function**.

Comment: The documentation will tell which is the right syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first function is a built-in **function** that is not associated with any class. You can view a list of all builtins available to you using `dir(__builtins__)`:

```
>>> dir(__builtins__)
'ArithmeticError', 'AssertionError', ...  'len', ... 'vars', 'zip']
```

`len()` is designed to return the size of any iterable, not just a string.

The second function is actually a **method** of the builtin class `str`. You can peruse the methods of `str` with `dir(str)`, and confirm `capitalize` is an instance method of `str`.

```
>>> 'capitalize' in dir(str)
True
```

Instance methods are invoked *on* the instances of the object, such as `'abc'.capitalize()`. This means that the call passes `abc` as an invisible argument to `capitalize`. Methods are meant to work only on instances of that class type.

Comment: I thank you all for your replies, I am new in Python and was I studying from here (tutorialspoint.com/python/python_strings.htm) were len() is registered as a built-in string method ...